# Pivot tables with a non-numerical value as a percentage of total column count

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have this data:

```
Name1  Day1  a
Name1  Day1  a
Name1  Day1  a
Name1  Day1  b
Name1  Day1  b
Name1  Day1  b
Name1  Day2  a
Name1  Day2  a
Name1  Day2  b
Name1  Day2  b
Name1  Day2  b
Name1  Day2  b
Name2  Day1  a
Name2  Day1  a
Name2  Day1  a
Name2  Day1  b
Name2  Day1  b
Name2  Day1  b
Name2  Day2  a
Name2  Day2  a
Name2  Day2  b
Name2  Day2  b
Name2  Day2  b
Name2  Day2  b
```

I'd like to use pivot_table so I'll have names as index and columns as days and a/a+b(as a percentage) as values. a and b values are non-numerical.

```
      Day1  Day2
Name1  %50  %30
Name2  %50  %30
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` + `size` to get the number counts of each group and then we'll reshape and use index alignment to perform the math.

```
# Get the size and reshape to a nicer format. `[*df]` is all columns.  
s = df.groupby([*df]).size().unstack(-2).rename_axis(index=[None, None], columns=None)

#         Day1  Day2
#Name1 a     3     2
#      b     3     4
#Name2 a     3     2
#      b     3     4

# a/(a+b)
s.xs('a', level=1).div(s.sum(level=0))

#       Day1      Day2
#Name1   0.5  0.333333
#Name2   0.5  0.333333
```

---

The last step works as follows. `DataFrame.xs` selects that subset from a MultiIndex. In this case, we take all of the rows with `'a'` on the first level of the index.

```
s.xs('a', level=1)
#       Day1  Day2
#Name1     3     2
#Name2     3     2
```

`sum` can also automatically groupby + sum over an index level. In this case, by summing over `level=0` we are accomplishing `(a+b)`, assuming `'a'` and `'b'` are the only possible values, for each Name and Day.

```
s.sum(level=0)
#       Day1  Day2
#Name1     6     6
#Name2     6     6
```

Now that these are two like-indexed DataFrames, the division aligns along both the index and columns.

Answer (score 0):

```python
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': {0: 'Name1', 1: 'Name1', 2: 'Name1', 3: 'Name1', 4: 'Name1', 5: 'Name1', 6: 'Name1', 7: 'Name1', 8: 'Name1', 9
   ...: : 'Name1', 10: 'Name1', 11: 'Name2', 12: 'Name2', 13: 'Name2', 14: 'Name2', 15: 'Name2', 16: 'Name2', 17: 'Name2', 18: 'Name2', 19: 'Name2
   ...: ', 20: 'Name2', 21: 'Name2', 22: 'Name2'},
   ...:  'Day1': {0: 'Day1', 1: 'Day1', 2: 'Day1', 3: 'Day1', 4: 'Day1', 5: 'Day2', 6: 'Day2', 7: 'Day2', 8: 'Day2', 9: 'Day2', 10: 'Day2', 11: 'D
   ...: ay1', 12: 'Day1', 13: 'Day1', 14: 'Day1', 15: 'Day1', 16: 'Day1', 17: 'Day2', 18: 'Day2', 19: 'Day2', 20: 'Day2', 21: 'Day2', 22: 'Day2'},
   ...: 
   ...:  'a': {0: 'a',1: 'a',2: 'b',3: 'b',4: 'b',5: 'a',6: 'a',7: 'b',8: 'b',9: 'b',10: 'b',11: 'a',12: 'a',13: 'a',14: 'b',15: 'b',16: 'b',17: '
   ...: a',18: 'a',19: 'b',20: 'b',21: 'b',22: 'b'}})
   ...: df.head()
Out[1]: 
   Name1  Day1  a
0  Name1  Day1  a
1  Name1  Day1  a
2  Name1  Day1  b
3  Name1  Day1  b
4  Name1  Day1  b

In [2]: import numpy as np
   ...: f = df.groupby(["Name1", "Day1"]).apply(lambda x:x.a.value_counts())

In [3]: f = pd.DataFrame(f.a / (f.a + f.b) * 100)
   ...: f = f.reset_index().set_index(['Name1', 'Day1']).unstack(['Day1'])

In [4]: f.columns=['Day1', 'Day2']
   ...: f.index= ['Name1', 'Name2']

In [5]: f
Out[5]: 
       Day1       Day2
Name1  40.0  33.333333
Name2  50.0  33.333333
```